# How to get one build for localization with @angular/localize?

Tags: angular, angular-localize

I've started an angular application. First it will only be available in english but then we will have to add translation. We started to use `@angular/localize` just to not have to go through the whole application when we will add other languages.

I modified the angular.json to look like this.

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "myapp": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        },
        "@schematics/angular:application": {
          "strict": true
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "i18n": {
        "sourceLocale": "en-US",
        "locales": {
          "fr": "src/locale/messages.fr.xlf",
          "en": "src/locale/messages.xlf"
        }
      },
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/myapp",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": ["src/favicon.ico", "src/assets"],
            "styles": ["src/styles.scss"],
            "scripts": [],
            "localize": true
          },
          "configurations": {
            "fr": {
              "localize": ["fr"]
            },
            "en": {
              "localize": ["en"]
            },
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ],
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "myapp:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "myapp:build:development"
            },
            "fr": {
              "browserTarget": "myapp:build:development,fr"
            },
            "en": {
              "browserTarget": "myapp:build:development,en"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "myapp:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": ["src/favicon.ico", "src/assets"],
            "styles": ["src/styles.scss"],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-eslint/builder:lint",
          "options": {
            "lintFilePatterns": ["src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.html"]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "myapp",
  "cli": {
    "defaultCollection": "@ngxs/schematics"
  }
}
```

But now, when I build, I've such kind of result:
[image]

It's like the whole project has been generated in 2 languages. But in my case, I need to have only one project, and be able to call some service to switch language. Also we don't want to have the language in the path, since it's an app that will be available only for authenticated users, and the language will come from their profile.

Is there a way to achieve this with @angular/localize?

Thank you

Comment: any solution you got?

Comment: @mohit As of today, I've learned that `@angular/localize` is working that way. We decided to go with `ngx-translate` and are quite happy with it.